# Project oriented questions

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes, when I obtain a answer for a question I raised another question.I would ask my questions in a way that will see that these questions are related to other questions I ask before. I thing this is interesting because it provides a kind of knowledge that not only solve isolated questions but also make projects. Until now I´ve been puttig hyperlinks in my questions with other related questions I did before but I wonder if there other way to generate a kind of information oriented to make projects and not only to get answer for isolated questions.
I think the solution is more than putting tags, I am looking for a resource that can be define projects, the differents part that they have and find interesting questions solved before for parts of the project you are doing.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's the "Related" box on the right, but apart from that - would these Projects be useful to someone other than the asker? I'm not convinced of that: it may be useful to me to get a reference for the time that I need OpenCV *and* jQuery *and* PostgreSQL, but who else will benefit from the Project formed by these disparate technologies?